# Getting "AuthenticationError" from Microsoft when retrieving photo in Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am querying Microsoft Graph with App-Only permissions since I'm acting on all users in the directory. When I make the query for the `onPremisesSamAccountName` with my token, I have no issues. However, when I attempt to retrieve the photo for the user (using the same token), I get the following:

```
StatusCode: 400 Bad Request
Error Code: AuthenticationError
Error Message: Error authenticating with resource
```

I have the following app-only permissions assigned in my tenant:

- User.Read.All (application, admin consented)
- Directory.Read.All (application, admin consented)

Details:

- URI: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myuser@domain.com/photo/$value`
- Scope: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`
- Content-type: `application/json`
- Authorization header: `"bearer _my token string_"`

Here is my request (in ColdFusion):

```html
<cfhttp method="get" charset="utf-8" url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myuser@domain.com/photo/$value" result="resp">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="bearer Oxfd989309sdf...">
</cfhttp>
```

The response I get back is what I showed above. When I run my token through http://jwt.calebb.net/, I don't see any scopes set.

I tried running this through Graph Explorer. I signed in as myself, then I ran the URI `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo`, the response I received was:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The photo wasn't found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ebae50f8-b636-4e61-9d92-eab4b48ef0c2",
            "date": "2019-08-08T19:13:50"
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that because I don't have a photo.

When I use the URI `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myuser@mydomain.com/photo/$value`, I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "40246947-57d6-4016-a55a-c1ad5f0736e4",
            "date": "2019-08-08T19:16:37"
        }
    }
}
```

I patterned my request after [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) where it shows a sample GET

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

Did I miss a step, or leave out a scope?

Comment: Does the user you're testing with have an Exchange Online mailbox provisioned, with a profile picture uploaded?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, no the user does not have a provisioned mailbox with photo. I knew I would get an error of some sort, but I wasn't expecting an authentication error. I also saw that my roles [directory.read.all, users.read.all] were present. So, the particular AuthenticationError I received, is that indicative of a lack of Exchange Online license?

Comment: I think @Marc has answered your question, you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run my token through http://jwt.calebb.net/, I don't see any
> scopes set.

When you get the token by using client credentials flow, you will get the permissions under roles.

[image]

> I tried running this through Graph Explorer. I signed in as myself,
> then I ran the URI https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo, the
> response I received was:404

Just like @Marc LaFleur said in the comment, make sure the user has an Exchange Online mailbox provisioned, with a profile picture uploaded.

Comment: Thank you for identifying that. Part of the issue was that I was trying to access photo on my test system, but Exchange Online was not a part of that. I added code to check for the photo, and if that doesn't work, retrieve the jpegPhoto attribute from Azure AD. It all works now.

Also, shout out to @Marc LaFleur for that generous bit of wisdom about Exchange Online.

Answer (score 1):

Graph v1.0 only supports retrieving photos from the Exchange mailbox. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions):

> Note This operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.

You will likely have better luck with the Beta version of [GET Photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta) as this supports pulling photos from both Exhange mailboxs and AAD profiles:

```html
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/photo/$value" result="resp" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="bearer Oxfd989309sdf...">
</cfhttp>
```